# Is there any way to find name of tabs open in same window using flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am working on a project and was wondering if there is any plugin or way to find the name of tabs open in current window.

Comment: No, the currently opened tabs information are only available if you are developing a browser plugin. Not possible from a flutter web app